# Don't print root element of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

#### HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="bill in data.budget.bills" class="ngDailyAmount"></div>
```

How do I suppress the div tag from outputting to the browser. I only want my directive html to show - not the parent div.

Comment: To elaborate, my ngDailyAmount has a templateUrl that points to an html doc that is just an <ul> and some <li>. I only want the <ul> and <li>s to show and not the parent <div>.

Comment: Do you mean make it so your `<div>` gets replaced with your `<ul>` from the template? For instance it would become `<ul class="ngDailyAmount">`?

Comment: No, I mean I don't want the <div>s to show at all. My directive is the only html I want output to the browser. My directive template contains all the html I want to show.

Comment: Perhaps making my directive the element would work, actually, but I was trying to keep it as is and figure out the way I want it.

Comment: Nope. My above guess didn't work.

Comment: did you try to use `replace:true` option for directives?

Comment: Thank you, @Yerken! That was it. I'm still learning here, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To substitute the root element on the directive you can use `replace:true` option

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, you can use *replace: true* to achieve what you spect. But it is a deprecated feature and might cause some issues in newer versions of angular, as a deprecated feature there is no support for it. Just try to adjust your code to the *no replacing* way.

Comment: From what I'm reading, it's not leaving. They're just not fixing bugs. However, I feel this is great information to have, and I will most definitely change my approach.